# How to get select value from overlay to show it on page in react

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Overlay File:

```
     const option=["a", "b", "c", "d"];
      export default class Add extends Component {

      constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {options: option};
      }

      onSelect(event) {
       this.setState({selectState: event.value});
     }

      render () {
      const { onClose } = this.props;
      const {options, selectState} = this.state;
        return (
       <Layer onClose={onClose} >
         <div >
         <Form>
         <FormField label="Device Categories (250)">
             <Select  value={selectState} options={options} 
           onChange={this.onSelect} /> 
       </FormField>
        <div>
         <Button type="submit" label="OK" href="#"
         onClick={onClose} />
       </div>
      </Form>
        </Box>

       </Layer>
       );
     }
    };
```

Main File:

```
var Category = React.createClass({
  render: function(props) {
    const { selectState, devicevalue } = this.props;

   return (
     <div>
     {devicevalue}
    </div>
     );
    }
     });
```

I want selectState value from the overlay to show in devicevalue
The problem is, when i select a value, and the overlay shows up, after I select a value in the overlay, the overlay disappears which is normal in reactjs. Now because the element does not exist how can I extract a value from it? I just want my select to get a value and show it as selected. BTW I cannot use normal  and  method.

Comment: How come nobody helps :(

Comment: You need to set the value in a store (flux,redux whatever framework you use) and grab it from the main component

Comment: Do you care to elaborate? What do you mean when you say set the value in store? can you give an example ?

Comment: Are you using redux , mobx, flux or reflux? Its an architecture/framework to help handle the non-view side, because react only handles the view side.